# Couchbase NoSQL Document Schema

Tags: couchbase, nosql

I am new to NoSQL and document based schemas and I am working on a Gym-based Training app. I am trying to figure out the best way to do the following:

There are a bunch of "base activities" each with variations. Below the base activity is #1 and the variations #2 to #8.

```
1|15º Decline Bench Press, Barbell, Close Grip
2|15º Decline Bench Press, Thick Barbell, Close Grip
3|15º Decline Bench Press, Barbell, Close Grip, With Chains
4|15º Decline Bench Press, Thick Barbell, Close Grip, With Chains

5|15º Decline Bench Press, Barbell, Close Grip, With Bands Assisting
6|15º Decline Bench Press, Thick Barbell, Close Grip, With Bands Assisting
7|15º Decline Bench Press, Barbell, Close Grip, With Bands Resisting
8|15º Decline Bench Press, Thick Barbell, Close Grip, With Bands Resisting
```

As each variation is considered an advanced training technique, I will not be offering a separate video showing technique, nor will there need to be any different text-based instructional information, thus it makes no sense for these variations to be in their own activity document, due to the large amounts of redundant data. The JSON of a proposed activity document can be seen below.

```
{
  "id": "a::1",
  "doctype": "activity",
  "lay_name": "15º Decline Bench Press, Barbell, Close Grip",
  "coach_name": "Bench Press, 15º Decline, Barbell, Close Grip",
  "type": "resistance",
  "author": "",
  "exp_level": "intermediate",
  "contraindicated": [
    "Shoulder Impingement"
  ],
  "technique_videos": {
    "correct": "/folder/folder/file1.mp4",
    "incorrect": "/folder/folder/file2.mp4"
  },
  "equipment": [
    "Barbell",
    "Decline Bench"
  ],
  "tags": [
    "Free Weight",
    "Mass Builder",
    "Indoor"
  ],
  "activity_variation": [
    {
      "variation": "thick_barbell",
      "lay_name": "15º Decline Bench Press, Thick Barbell, Close Grip",
      "coach_name": "Bench Press, 15º Decline, Thick Barbell, Close Grip"
    },
    {
     "variation": "with_chains",
      "lay_name": "15º Decline Bench Press, Barbell, Close Grip, With Chains",
      "coach_name": "Bench Press, 15º Decline, Barbell, Close Grip, With Chains"
    },
    {
     "variation": "thick_barbell_with_chains",
      "lay_name": "15º Decline Bench Press, Thick Barbell, Close Grip, With Chains",
      "coach_name": "Bench Press, 15º Decline, Thick Barbell, Close Grip, With Chains"
    },
    {
     "variation": "with_bands_assisting",
      "lay_name": "15º Decline Bench Press, Barbell, Close Grip, With Bands Assisting",
      "coach_name": "Bench Press, 15º Decline, Barbell, Close Grip, With Bands Assisting"
    },
    {
     "variation": "thick_barbell_with_bands_assisting",
      "lay_name": "15º Decline Bench Press, Thick Barbell, Close Grip, With Bands Assisting",
      "coach_name": "Bench Press, 15º Decline, Thick Barbell, Close Grip, With Bands Assisting"
    },
    {
     "variation": "with_bands_resisting",
      "lay_name": "15º Decline Bench Press, Barbell, Close Grip, With Bands Resisting",
      "coach_name": "Bench Press, 15º Decline, Barbell, Close Grip, With Bands Resisting"
    },
    {
     "variation": "thick_barbell_with_bands_resisting",
      "lay_name": "15º Decline Bench Press, Thick Barbell, Close Grip, With Bands Resisting",
      "coach_name": "Bench Press, 15º Decline, Thick Barbell, Close Grip, With Bands Resisting"
    }
  ],
  "description": "Excellent mass builder that focuses on the lower part of the pec.",
  "technique_description": [
    "1. bla bla",
    "2. Bla bla",
    "3. Bla bla",
    "4. Bla bla"
  ],
  "prime_mover": "Pectoralis Major",
  "focus": "Pectoralis Major - Sternal Head"
}
```

Firstly these activities (or exercises if you prefer) will need to be queried and then presented as separate activities eg:

Secondly they will also need to be associated with (Gym programs and) individual workouts (that are comprised of activities) and the users record of what they lifted (reps, sets, weight) for a particular exercise, on a workout, on a particular day. So I am trying to figure out the best way to design the schema to accommodate for this. I am also thinking that users should be able to specify in the settings what equipment they have access to and if they don't have things eg. chains, then they don't get shown associated exercises when they query the exercise list.

Questions:

1. Can someone suggest a better schema/process then what I have above? Perhaps a separate document that takes an activity key and stores the associated variations for that key (activity) would be better? Suggestions please?
2. Given the answer to #1, how should I handle these name variations when storing the user's data from a workout, for eg:

"15º Decline Bench Press, Thick Barbell, Close Grip, With Chains"